# Gradle error with compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[4,5)'

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.login_androidlogin"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //CounterFAB
    compile 'com.github.andremion:counterfab:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[4,5)'

    compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    compile 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.1'
    compile 'com.stepstone.apprating:app-rating:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.1'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    compile 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

After i add compile `com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[4,5)` into the build.gradle, then it shows the error.

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.1
```

So whats the problem and how to solve it ?
All the code is working well before i add the compile `com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[4,5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use support libraries starting from version `26.0.0` you need to add Google's Maven repository to your project's build.gradle file as described here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }
```

For Android Studio 3.0.0 and above you can just write `google()` like this

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }
```

And for Facebook SDK you have to add `mavenCentral()` to the  `buildscript { repositories {}}` section as mentioned here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() 
    }
}
```

You can also specify the version like

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.28.0'
```

instead of `[4,5)`

you can get the latest version from their github:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk